# Route one ip from wifi to ethernet

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, ethernet

I got this network:

[image: network]

I run an application on my RPi3 (hosting on 10.0.0.1) and I plug it on a server (which run an other application hosted on 20.0.0.1). I set up my raspberry as an access point wifi that able connection from a computer, and I can access to the application on the RPi (10.0.0.1) but not the application on the server (20.0.0.1). How do I reach 20.0.0.1 from the computer ?

I can't use bridge, because I still need to access 10.0.0.1. 
I failed using route.

Does someone have an idea ?

**EDIT :** `ip route add 20.0.0.1 via 20.0.0.1 dev eth0` don't work.

Comment: Have you tried with `iptables`? I have not used it but dig around it maybe it might be useful

Comment: Add a static route on each router so that it aware the other network exist. Since you didn't provide any information about your router configuration so the answer can't be specific, but this should give you the general direction to work with

Comment: Thanks ! But why do i need to edit the server's route ? Isn't it enough if i do something like 
"ip route add 20.0.0.1 via 20.0.0.1 dev eth0"

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but you would need to some setting to make it persist upon reboot. such as set it up at dhcpcd.conf.

Comment: Thank you a lot about your answers, but it doesn't work :/ I can add  "ip route add 20.0.0.1 via 20.0.0.1 dev eth0" but when I try to access "20.0.0.1" from my browser it fails. Do you have another idea ?